# Can you make Windows 2000 compatible with newer pragrams?

Tags: updates, compatibility, windows-2000

Is it possible to update Win2k with newer files to make newer programs run on it or would that cause mayhem in the system?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Look up KernelEx.

Answer (score 1):

The OS supplies certain frameworks and software to other software: these are called "dependencies".

Some newer programs have dependencies that will not run on Windows 2000, for any of a very large number of reasons. Because these programs require these dependencies, and these dependencies cannot run on Windows 2000, the programs will not run.

In other words: If the program is not compatible with Windows 2000, you are out of luck.

Note: Just because a program doesn't say that it supports Windows 2000 does not mean you are out of luck. The best thing to do is to try. If you have a specific application you are trying to run on Windows 2000 you may wish to submit a different question with that specific application so that we can advise regarding it. However, you will need to have tried to install it already, and searched for any error messages it returns. This is called "homework", and we like to see it because it indicates you are serious about the question and the solution.